# Making background image translucent

Tags: css

I have a background image for whole page and another for content div. What I  want is the background image of content div should be semi transparent so that some of the background image(for the whole page) below it should also be visible.
I also tried reducing the opacity of my .png background file using image editor but it didn't show my the background below , instead the image just got lightened.

Comment: Do you also have `background-color` set? If yes, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nature-q-c-1600-1600-10.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-600-500-7.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: but this changes the opacity of the inner text also which I don't want

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just that the pseudo-element is sitting on top of the text. Fixed that with a z-index.

Answer (score 0):

To make a div transparent you can use:

```
.thediv{
    background-color: transparent
}
```

**Edit:** Semi transparent with:

```
.thediv{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/24419/pexels-photo-24419-large.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/940/sky-sunset-sand-night-large.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jw6c79L/

Comment: but this changes the opacity of the inner text also which I don't want